# pandas plot xticks on x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have a working code that displays a panda dataframe as 2 line graphs in a chart. I also have a dataframe that displays a bar graph on the same chart. For the 2 dataframes, i have date for the x-axis. Because the two dataframes have dates, my axis end up just having integers (1,2,3,4,5,6...) instead of the date.

I thought this line `df1 = df.set_index(['date'])` specifies what i want as the x-axis already and when i dont plot the bar graph on the chart, the dates show up nicely, but when i do plot the bar graph, the integers show up on the axis instead.

My 2 dataframes:

```
df1:
date      line1  line2
2015-01-01 15.00  23.00
2015-02-01 18.00  10.00

df2:
date      quant  
2015-01-01 500 
2015-02-01 600
```

My code:

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame(result, columns =[ 'date','line1', 'line2']) 
df1 = df.set_index(['date'])

df2 =pd.DataFrame(quantity, columns =[ 'quant','date']) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
ax2.set_ylim(0,2100)

df1.line1.plot( color = 'red', ax = ax)
df1.line2.plot( color = 'blue', ax = ax)
df2.["quant"].plot(kind = 'bar', ax =ax2, width =0.4)
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

```
df1:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 12 entries, 0 to 11
Data columns (total 3 columns):
date        12 non-null object
line1    12 non-null float64
line2     12 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 384.0+ bytes
None

df2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns (total 2 columns):
quant         11 non-null int64
date    11 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 264.0+ bytes
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `ax.plot(df1.date, df1.line1)` and `matplotlib.pyplot` will automatically take care of the date.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your data
# ===================================
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS'), line1=np.random.randint(10, 30, 12), line2=np.random.randint(20, 25, 12)))

Out[64]: 
         date  line1  line2
0  2015-01-01     22     22
1  2015-02-01     25     21
2  2015-03-01     10     20
3  2015-04-01     13     21
4  2015-05-01     13     21
5  2015-06-01     17     20
6  2015-07-01     19     21
7  2015-08-01     29     24
8  2015-09-01     28     23
9  2015-10-01     14     20
10 2015-11-01     16     23
11 2015-12-01     22     20



df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS'), quant=100*np.random.randint(3, 10, 12)))

Out[66]: 
         date  quant
0  2015-01-01    500
1  2015-02-01    600
2  2015-03-01    300
3  2015-04-01    400
4  2015-05-01    600
5  2015-06-01    800
6  2015-07-01    600
7  2015-08-01    600
8  2015-09-01    900
9  2015-10-01    300
10 2015-11-01    400
11 2015-12-01    400

# plotting
# ===================================
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ax.plot(df1.date, df1.line1, label='line1', c='r')
ax.plot(df1.date, df1.line2, label='line2', c='b')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('quant')
ax2.bar(df2.date, df2.quant, width=20, alpha=0.1, color='g', label='quant')
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

[image]

Follow-up (Updates):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your data
# ===================================
np.random.seed(0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS'), line1=np.random.randint(10, 30, 12), line2=np.random.randint(20, 25, 12))).set_index('date')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=12, freq='MS'), quant=100*np.random.randint(3, 10, 12))).set_index('date')
df2 = df2.drop(df2.index[4])
print(df1)
print(df2)
            line1  line2
date                    
2015-01-01     22     22
2015-02-01     25     21
2015-03-01     10     20
2015-04-01     13     21
2015-05-01     13     21
2015-06-01     17     20
2015-07-01     19     21
2015-08-01     29     24
2015-09-01     28     23
2015-10-01     14     20
2015-11-01     16     23
2015-12-01     22     20
            quant
date             
2015-01-01    500
2015-02-01    600
2015-03-01    300
2015-04-01    400
2015-06-01    800
2015-07-01    600
2015-08-01    600
2015-09-01    900
2015-10-01    300
2015-11-01    400
2015-12-01    400

# plotting
# ===================================
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ax.plot(df1.index, df1.line1, label='line1', c='r')
ax.plot(df1.index, df1.line2, label='line2', c='b')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('quant')
ax2.bar(df2.index, df2.quant, width=20, alpha=0.1, color='g', label='quant')
ax.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got a this error: ax.plot(df.date, df.line1, label='before', c='r')                                                              ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-05-01

Comment: @jxn which line raises that error? Are you running the sample code in my post or applying it to your own dataset?

Comment: sorry, it is my own dataset

Comment: @jxn Maybe try `df2.reindex(df1.index)` to populate `NaN` for that missing date and then plot. If that doesn't solve the problem, can you upload your sample data file (dropbox sharelink or google driver) so that I can take a look at what might go wrong.

Comment: could it be due to my df1 having an extra month in there( it has 11 months) while my df2 only has 10 months.

Comment: @jxn yes, I can see it. I've modified the code and updated the post. Let me know whether it works out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82987/discussion-between-jxn-and-jianxun-li).

Comment: @jxn I just spot a typo in my code. Could you please try it again?

Comment: got this error about the index:     `df = df.set_index(date).sort_index()
NameError: name 'date' is not defined`.

Comment: @jxn How about this?     `df = df.set_index('date').sort_index()`    `df2 = df2.set_index('date').sort_index()`     `df2 = df2.reindex(df.index).fillna(0)`

Comment: That didnt work, but this did: `df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index() df2 = df2.set_index(['date']).sort_index() df2 = df2.reindex(df.index).fillna(0)` but it brought me back to the original error: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-05-01`. Before when i used df.plot() instead of ax.plot, i got the plots though

Comment: @jxn I need to see your datafile and your full code script. I've tested my sample code when df2 does not have '2015-05-1'. It still works well. Please have a look.

Comment: @jianxuan Li, i think it may be an error with my data type. ive edited my post with the data types, perhaps the error lies in the date type?

Comment: @jxn very likely. To convert `date` from object to datetime, use `df1.date = pd.to_datetime(df1.date)` and then check again whether the date column is of type datetime64. Do the same for `df2` and then proceed with the plotting code.

Comment: ok i think we are getting close, error came from bar plot now:     `ax2.bar(df2.index, df2.query, width=20, alpha=0.1, color='g', label='query')
AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 12 or scalar`

Comment: @jxn check the length of df2.index and df2.query   height in bar plot is df2.query

Comment: `len(df2.index):12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tera_con.py", line 54, in <module>
    print len(df2.query)
TypeError: object of type 'instancemethod' has no len()`

Comment: @jxn what is df2.query exactly? print it out, i thought it's df2.quant? from your recent updates in the post, it should be int64.

Comment: yes it is int64 as displayed in the edit in my post above. only when i did df2["quant"] did i get `12` also. df.quant doesnt work somehow. it should be df2.quant

Comment: @jxn so why in bar plot, you try to plot df.query?  i just realised df.query is a pandas function. is that your typo?

Comment: it worked! had to change the bar plot code to this: `ax2.bar(df2.index, df2["quant"], width=20, alpha=0.1, color='g', label='quant')` . It is poor naming on my part..i think we know what the cause is now.